# How to render Thymeleaf template from Servlet Filter?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, filter, thymeleaf

I know, that during JSPs, it's just `request.getRequestDispatcher("path..").forward(request, response);`

However:

1. if I'll just provide root / path, it addresses servlet mapped at /. So, no template rendering occurs;
2. In this case, images and styles and etc (static content) are spoiled.. not loaded.. I believe, it happens, because Thymeleaf is not just a page, but is being rendered.

Any help how to render Thymeleaf template, which lives in `/resources/templates` from Servlet Filter, by `request.getRequestDispatcher("template.html").forward(request, response);` or any elsehow?

Comment: Why? What do you want to achieve? Why are you bypassing Spring here?

Comment: Deliberately :) I just want to achieve this with Servlet API. JSPs are Servlets, that's the clear point, and again, I know that I can forward request/response to RequestDispatchet of HttpServletRequest, but what if I want to do what I described above?

Thymeleaf is rendered simply - matching the returned String value from  the controller.. anything similar possible here?

Comment: Thymeleaf uses a different means of rendering (and I suggest you research how Spring MVC with view rendering works) then JSP and as such what you tried won't work. You will manually have to render the page and return the result.